# Как получить письма из Gmail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, imap

Требуется получить письмо из Gmail. Пробовал следующий код:

```
import imaplib, email
def read_email_from_gmail():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login('mymail@gmail.com','mypass')
    mail.select('inbox')

    type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
    mail_ids = data[0]

    id_list = mail_ids.split()
    first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
    latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])


    for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id, -1):
        type, data = mail.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)' )

        for response_part in data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                test = str(response_part)
                msg = email.message_from_string(test)
                email_subject = msg['subject']
                email_from = msg['from']
                print('From : ' + email_from + '\n')
                print('Subject : ' + email_subject + '\n')


read_email_from_gmail()
```

Он не сработал. Как реализовать?

---

PS (прим.ред.: перенесено из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1167524/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-gmail/1167585#comment2027145_1167524))
Но попробуем на примере этого кода. При запуске выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
print('From : ' + email_from + '\n'); 
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str".
```

Поправил, заменив `print('From : ' + email_from + '\n')` на `print(email_from)`.
В итоге код зацикливается, выводя `None`. К тому же, в вопросе явно указано "как реализовать", а не "как исправить данный код"

Comment: у вас влючена `2-step verification` в Google?

Comment: @MaxU Дело не в логине в почту, если вы об этом

Comment: Тогда укажите в чем проблема, чтобы мы не угадывали...

Comment: @MaxU проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать. Код предоставил в связи с тем, что часто просят показать, что именно я пробовал. Но попробуем на примере этого кода. При запуске выдаёт следующую ошибку: "print('From : ' + email_from + '\n'); TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str". Поправил, заменив  "print('From : ' + email_from + '\n')" на "print(email_from)". В итоге код зацикливается, выводя "None" К тому же в вопросе явно указано "как реализовать", а не "как исправить данный код"

Comment: [Здесь](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) уже смотрели?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
import re
```

---

сначала выбираем папку `All Mail`:

```
In [311]: folder = [re.sub(r'.*?("\[G[^"]*").*', r'\1', f.decode("utf-8"))  for f in mail.list()[1] if br"\All " in f][0]

In [312]: mail.select(folder)
Out[312]: ('OK', [b'9355'])
```

ищем письма, в заголовке которых содержится слово `"test"`:

```
In [313]: typ, data = mail.search(None, '(SUBJECT "test")')
```

список `ID` найденных писем:

```
In [314]: data
Out[314]: [b'1873 1875 1876 1878 1879 3047 3088 4607 4625 5176 5299 5681 7074 8667 9261']
```

читаем и парсим одно из найденных писем:

```
In [315]: typ, d = mail.fetch('1879', '(RFC822)')

In [316]: msg = email.message_from_bytes(d[0][1])
```

результат:

```
In [317]: msg["subject"]
Out[317]: 'Re: test'

In [318]: msg["from"]
Out[318]: 'Max ****** <max.******@gmail.com>'

In [324]: msg.keys()
Out[324]:
['MIME-Version',
 'Received',
 'In-Reply-To',
 'References',
 'Date',
 'Delivered-To',
 'Message-ID',
 'Subject',
 'From',
 'To',
 'Content-Type',
 'Content-Transfer-Encoding']

In [325]: msg["Received"]
Out[325]: 'by 10.86.83.11 with HTTP; Tue, 27 Jan 2009 02:39:15 -0800 (PST)'

In [327]: msg["Content-Transfer-Encoding"]
Out[327]: 'base64'
```

Comment: как собственно текст письма получить?